# Method doesn't override an inherited method

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I am working on android studio with flutter and learning flutter .there i have make multiple page so i created a `page(HomePage)` in `home.dart file` but my dart analysis provides a error saying that :

> info: Method doesn't override an inherited method.
>   (override_on_non_overriding_method at [flutter_course]
>   lib/pages/home.dart:7)

```
import 'packages:flutter/materia.dart';

 import '../product_manager.dart';

 class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('EasyList')
       ),
       body: ProductManager(),
     );
   }
}
```

Should run without any error

Comment: `flutter/materia.dart` doesn't exists

Comment: Thank you so much can you please help me with this error:error: The method 'Scaffold' isn't defined for the class 'HomePage'. (undefined_method at [flutter_course] lib/pages/home.dart:8)

Answer (score 0):

You imported the `material` library in an incorrect way, replace it with :

```
import 'packages:flutter/material.dart';
```

and for those of you who are running flutter for the first time, edit the `pubspec.yaml` file of your project and add the following:

```
 flutter:
   uses-material-design: true
```

then run the command `flutter packages get`, and after that it should be working.

Comment: Thankyou it sorted that one but now it is showing these errors: => error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'packages:flutter/material.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [flutter_course] lib/pages/home.dart:1)
error: Classes can only extend other classes. (extends_non_class at [flutter_course] lib/pages/home.dart:5)
error: Undefined class 'StatelessWidget'. (undefined_class at [flutter_course] lib/pages/home.dart:5)
error: Undefined class 'Widget'. (undefined_class at [flutter_course] lib/pages/home.dart:7)

Comment: Yeah sure wait.

Comment: I dont know how to provide printshot here?

Comment: is this your first time running flutter ?

Comment: there are chat rooms but you have to earn more reputation to participate in them, for the recent time try improving your skill by reading flutter docs and SO posts.

Comment: I already added that in my pubspec.yaml but still there are  issues and my flutter commands are not running..It is saying that flutter command not found